# Should I have to use no-hoist for all packages in a monorepo with react-native-web?

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, monorepo, react-native-web

I'm developing an SPA which I'm serving up using Rails and the ruby webpacker implementation. I have my client folder split up into a yarn monorepo for my `web`, `native`, and `common` code so I can reuse as much as possible using react-native-web.

So far, for the native part I have to use the `nohoist` directive for any library I want to use. When I run the android dev server, it can't bundle anything in the hoisted node_modules folder, so anything I want to use I have to tell it to install in the local node_modules folder using `nohoist`.

I'm wondering if this is how these projects are supposed to be set up, if this is normal? Should I be using something like Lerna to manage symlinking and package hoisting? Have I missed a step or a library somewhere when setting this up?

Answer (score 2):

I use yarn workspaces and lerna in a mono-repo and symlinking wasn't working for our react-native project.

I added the following to the child package's package.json (the react native package in the mono-repo) which prevents hoisting of anything in the react native package:

```
"workspaces": {
  "nohoist": [
    "*",
  ]
},
```

I'm assuming this would be similar to react-native-web.

We tried lots of other methods which did not work and it did seem like hoisting in general was not compatible with react native based projects.

Comment: Not fair to say that "hoisting.. was not compatible w RN based projects."  You can let the workspace mechanism hoist, but you have to make sure the appropriate settings get updated in metro.config.js, and also in the gradle.build of the android build.  There are several articles around on goolge about this.